# ES - return an error to user in resolve of a promise

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise

I have a very common scenario where I need to check if the user already exists in database? if yes, then return back an error to the user saying username already exists. I am using `mongoose` and its `findOne` method:

```
exports.registerUser = async (req, res) => {

    await userModel.findOne({'email': req.body.email}).exec().then((result) => {
        //user is already present in the db
        respondWithError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "The user exists in the db")
    }).catch(error => {
        // user is not in the db - save
        saveTheUserToDb(req)
        res.render('home');
    })
}
```

here is my `respondWithError` function:

```
const respondWithError = (httpStatus, message) => {
    throw new BaseError(httpStatus, message)
}
```

and here is the `BaseError`

```
class BaseError extends Error {
    constructor(httpStatus, message) {
        super();
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus
        this.message = message
    }
}
```

The issue is that when `findOne(...).exex()` comes back and promise is resolved `respondWithError` is called which leads the execution directly into `catch` block where the user is saved in the DB which obviously is not what is intended.

What is the right way of sending back an error when it has to be in the resolve of a promise?

Comment: Use `.then(throwError, saveNewUser)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`. However, in the onerror callback make sure to check that the `error` is actually a "not found" one, not some other kind of error.

Comment: That's how promises work... if you `throw` inside a `.then()` callback, it will be caught by any `.catch()` following it. Since you are in an async function, you might be able to do something like:

`exports.registerUser = async (req, res) => {

  const foundUser = await userModel.findOne({'email': req.body.email}).exec();
  if (foundUser) { return respondWithError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "The user exists in the db"); }

  saveTheUserToDb(req)
  res.render('home');
}`

Comment: @andersryanc I get this ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The user exists in the db``` in logs, and I dont get the reponse, the request never gets a response

Comment: May be I wrong. But I'm think - your respondWithError function call BaseError (with super() call to parent class Error), whats why .catch {} block is applyed, and you got you db error message. I'm think it's not a good idea to save user in catch block anyway... Just use node debug tool (or simply console.log) to view thru call stack.

Comment: It sounds like it's making it to my suggested `if (foundUser)` block and it's calling your `respondWithError()` function? ... I guess the larger question is how you are handling those `BaseErrors`? You must have a "middleware" / "error handler" at the end of your express setup which finally catches those and does something like `res.status(this.httpStatus).send(this.message)`? Normally I would just call `res.status(500).send("error message")` right in the handler, or have a helper func at least that receives `req, res` along with your args and calls that for you, instead of throwing an error.

Comment: @andersryanc yes I have a express middleware setup that catches the error, the issues is not catching it, the issue when I throw the error in ```resolve``` it leads to ```catch``` block which is how its supposed to work, so I replaced ```.then``` with a ```try catch```. os if user exists I ```respondeWithError``` in ```try``` block and which leads to ```catch``` and in ```catch``` I just do ```next(err)``` and that seems to have fixed the issue.